# In Zone file terms, how is a subdomain represented?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, dns-zone

I am trying to add a subdomain to my zone file but I'm not sure how to add it.

Should I use `sub.domain.com A 1.0.0.1` or `sub A domain.com` or `sub C 1.0.0.1`?

I know this is a very newbie question but I could not find any dummy guides that explain this concept simply.

Comment: You use the A record the same way you would for a regular domain. It depends on the control panel you are using, but you add a new record, put in the domain, and the IP it is on.

Comment: @DanBig Thanks. So, I should be using `sub.domain.com A 1.0.0.1`?

Comment: yes,that is correct

Comment: *Almost* correct; you need the extra . after .com as per Sanman4's answer.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't technically call this a subdomain. This is just an A record. A subdomain would usually be delegated to another DNS server, or at a minimum have it's own SOA record (not just an A record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the zone file for `example.com` domain, you use

```
sub.example.com. A 1.0.0.1
```

OR

```
sub A 1.0.0.1
```

They are equivalent. Note the dot **after** the .com, without the trailing dot you are going to define sub.example.com.example.com, which is probably not what you meant to do.

There's a decend guide at [DNS for Rocket Scientists, chapter 8](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/#zone)